# JavaFX: How to combine multiple images into one?

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, overlay

I'm working on a chess program and I'm using JavaFX for the GUI.

How do I combine multiple images into one image to display the combined image in an ImageView?

I don't want to make images for both tile colors with every piece, but overlay the empty tile image with a piece image.

Comment: An `ImageView` can only contain one `Image` at a time, though you can share the same `Image` between multiple `ImageView`s.

Comment: I know that, I'm looking for a way to combine two images to one and then display that in the imageView. I edited my question, I think that may not have been clear

Comment: In that case, one option is to simply stack the two `ImageView`s on top of each other (e.g. using a `StackPane`). I believe if the chess pieces are transparent everywhere except for the actual piece the underlying node should show through.

Comment: Create board as GridPane of StackPanes. Every StackPane should have black/white background colour and one piece on it presented as SvgPath. Svgs are available [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_chess_pieces)

Comment: You can use StackPane, and overlay imageview inside it

Answer (score -2):

There are several options of how to combine two (or more) images. The easiest probably is to draw your images onto a canvas and then take a snapshot of this canvas. But then one would have to ask the question why you would want to do that at all, because you could just use the canvas directly and there would be no need to use an ImageView.